# <Angular CLI> Use script inside HTML with a parameter from another .ts file

Tags: html, angular, function, typescript, angular-cli

Good afternoon!

I'm sorry if I'm unable to get this clear, but here's the problem:

i have a file named "heroes.ts", where I have many objects for a "Hero" class (which is exported from another file), here you can see a fragment of it -->

```
import { Hero, Villain } from '../hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [

{ id: 78251, name: 'Fareeha Amari',            codename: 'Pharah',        alive:true  },
{ id: 15964, name: 'Gengi Shimada',            codename: 'Gengi',         alive:true  },
{ id: 21345, name: 'Angela Ziegler',           codename: 'Mercy',         alive:true  },
{ id: 84519, name: 'Lena Oxton',               codename: 'Tracer',        alive:true  },
{ id: 64518, name: 'Jeese Mccree',             codename: 'Mccree',        alive:true  }, 

..............]
```

these pieces of information are used inside another file, called "heroes.component.html". After a certain point, i need to call this data. And I do it like this (mostly, without any problem):

```
<h2>Heroes</h2>

  <ul id="heroes">

<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero" 
(click)="onSelect(hero)"> 

  <p> ID: {{hero.id}} | {{hero.name}}, codename {{hero.codename}}. 
  <!-- Until here, everything is AOK and printed --> 
  Status: <script> aliveDead()  </script> </p>  
  <!-- Here lies the preoblem, nothing gets printed after "Status --> 
</li>
```

You must be wondering where is aliveDead(), i have this function in this same file:

```
 <script>

    function aliveDead()
    {
      if( hero.alive == 1 )
      {
        return "Active";
      }
      else
      {
        return "Dead";
      }
    }
//OBS: i tried using hero.alive and hero as parameters for this function
//it does not work
</script>
```

I need to make this function run inside the script tags and return me a value that can be printed after the "Status" using, as parameter, the information provided from the first chunck of code ( "heroes.ts" )

Again, i'm sorry if i can't really explain that well, but i did my best

thanks anyway,

chab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `heroes.ts` component where you have `hero.id`, etc. you can define `aliveDead` instead.

```
Status: {{aliveDead(hero)}}
```

If you really want `aliveDead` to be defined separately, you can just put it in a separate file. Then you can import it in `heroes.ts`:

```
import { aliveDead } from 'path/to/aliveDead.ts';

@Component(...)
class HeroesList {
  ...
  // Assign your declared function to a component property
  aliveDead = aliveDead;
}
```

---

Another more efficient way to do this would be to create a pipe:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
/**
 * Pass-through pipe that mocks the `translate` pipe used for L10n for tests
 */
@Pipe({ name: 'aliveDead' })
export class HeroStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(hero) {
    if (hero.status === '1') {
      return 'Active';
    }
    return 'Dead';
  }
}
```

Then you will have to add this pipe to your module declarations. In your template you will be able to use `Status: {{hero | aliveDead}}`